# How to dynamically scroll focus a particular highlighted div

Tags: jquery, html, css

How to dynamically scroll to focus a particular highlighted div? am trying to scroll to focus a specific div has class highlighted.How can i solve this?

```
<div class="row">
<p>123</p>
</div>
<div class="row">
<p>123</p>
</div>
<div class="row">
<p>123</p>
</div>
<div class="row">
<p>123</p>
</div>
<div class="row highlighted">
<p>123</p>
</div>
<div class="row">
<p>123</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In simple js:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("row highlighted")[0].scrollIntoView();
```

or in jquery:

```
$( ".row highlighted")[0].scrollIntoView();
```

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName("row highlighted").scrollIntoView();  it shows error not a function

Comment: Yep, sorry it returns a collection since you can have multiple element with the same id, I added a [0] to select only the first element returned.

Comment: what [0] means?

Comment: the getElementsByClassName function doesn't return a single element since multiple elements can have the same class (unlike ids). So it returns a collection (sort of array) the [0] is to select the first element of the array.

Answer (score 2):

Try with jquery `position().top`

```js
$(document).on('click','button',function(){
var s  = $('.highlighted').position().top;
$('body').scrollTop(s)
})
```

```css
.row{
padding:50px;
border:1px solid red;
}
.highlighted{
border:2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>scroll highlighted</button>
<div class="row">
<p>123</p>
</div>
<div class="row">
<p>123</p>
</div>
<div class="row">
<p>123</p>
</div>
<div class="row">
<p>123</p>
</div>
<div class="row highlighted">
<p>123</p>
</div>
<div class="row">
<p>123</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed use:

```
element.scrollIntoView();
```

**Be careful**: if you are using VueJs, you may have problems trying to use Refs instead.
Even in VueJs, you should use a `document.getElementById`.

Answer (score -1):

Use jQuery `scrollIntoView`:

```
$(".ClssName").scrollIntoView();
```

Comment: Your answer should add a different solution to the problem. Unfortunately, this is exactly the same as the accepted answer.